# Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, bluez

I have checked all the necessary packages required for Bluetooth to work as `bluez` is installed but it doesn't work. the output of`dpkg --status bluez` shows conflicts with `bluez-audio` and `bluez-utils` Here is the output:

```
srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ dpkg --status bluez
Package: bluez
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 2544
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 4.101-0ubuntu13.1
Replaces: bluez-audio (<= 3.36-3), bluez-input, bluez-network, bluez-serial, bluez-utils (<= 3.36-3), udev (<< 170-1)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.1.1), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0), libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libudev1 (>= 183), libusb-0.1-4 (>= 2:0.1.12), sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) | file-rc (>= 0.8.16), module-init-tools, udev (>= 170-1), lsb-base, dbus, python3-dbus
Suggests: bluez-hcidump
Breaks: udev (<< 170-1)
Conflicts: bluez-audio (<= 3.36-3), bluez-utils (<= 3.36-3)
Conffiles:
 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf ab36f00296c5d1f7ce78db671fb4338a
 /etc/bluetooth/main.conf 4c5ea920c35ec67225e01832e3276516
 /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf 0a87d3eddd29683c1456688907e67b4f
 /etc/bluetooth/network.conf 0c7497c405b963382ff71789d0730abd
 /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf 6bc1fef4f5fe083d34e953ec3dd70bfd
 /etc/bluetooth/proximity.conf b75823a140e00905d41465c380bf89fe
 /etc/bluetooth/serial.conf 5dcc15dd1153ddebbd41612da9b642e5
 /etc/bluetooth/input.conf 4bebcedeed8770b1aea07eefc5c35a52
 /etc/init/bluetooth.conf e6b0122c1e5cd56016859a0767a8cfcb
 /etc/init.d/bluetooth 6381b89fd1996a2d827e0e81f553477a
Description: Bluetooth tools and daemons
 This package contains tools and system daemons for using Bluetooth devices.
 .
 BlueZ is the official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack. It is an Open Source
 project distributed under GNU General Public License (GPL).
Homepage: http://www.bluez.org
Original-Maintainer: Debian Bluetooth Maintainers <pkg-bluetooth-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/repos/flasky$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b45e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: And what is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: @Pilot6 `Linux srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC 4.4.0-64-generic #85~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 12:10:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: This device works with the 4.8 kernel for sure. It worked with older kernels with the help of a custom module. I did not test it with the 4.4.

Comment: It worked after I updated the kernel via `Software Updater` and stopped working after some time. I am thinking of a config issue rather than with the kernel.